# Do notifications of conference papers' acceptance/rejection sent to all the papers' authors at the same time?

Tags: publications, conference

I have two inquiries, please.

1. Suppose that authors X, Y, and Z submit 3 different papers to the same conference. Will they all get notifications of acceptance/rejection at the same time (or a short period of time) or not necessarily?
2. Is it possible to get a notification of paper acceptance/rejection before the notification deadline?

Comment: Everything is possible, no one knows except for the organizers.

Comment: @Mark Everything may be possible *per se*, but experiences can show what's likely to happen and what not.

Comment: Why I voted to reopen: while this can be categorized as a question strongly enough depending on individual factors, the question itself asks about "if it depends on individual factors and general possibilities". The provided answers also explain why itdepends on individual factors and what are the possibilities. However, I also see why it can remain closed, just wanted to explicitly write about my reasonings.

Comment: 2) Yes, it can be desk-rejected if it is out of scope (mainly journal) or if the conference has a policy of pre-review by senior PC / meta reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

In my field (software engineering):

> 1. Suppose that authors X, Y, and Z submit 3 different papers to the same conference. Will they all get notifications of acceptance/rejection at the same time (or a short period of time) or not necessarily?

By and large, for most conferences, yes. But there are exceptions: For a conference with separate thematic tracks, it might happen that the tracks send the notifications at separate times. I have also seen very few individual cases of conferences where individual notifications were sent late, which made a poor impression on me (something that very good conferences want to avoid).

> 2- Is it possible to get a notification of paper acceptance/rejection before the notification deadline?

Absolutely, yes. From my experience, this is actually more common for top conferences than for other conferences.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the conference management system (Microsoft CMT’s platform is notoriously annoying, sending out notifications in what seems like random batches, sometimes hours apart), the chairs’ understanding of the configurations (some platforms offer a lot of different notifications options which may cause confusion at setup), and the conference size (lots of papers - likelier that systems crash or misbehave in unpredictable ways).